# Integer convertion with Flow Automate

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I'm getting this message after test my flow:

> The variable 'subAccountId' of type 'Integer' cannot be initialized or
> updated with value '123' of type 'String'. The variable 'subAccountId'
> only supports values of types 'Integer'.

[image]

I've tried:

- @int(THE_VARIABLE)
- @int(variables(THE_VARIABLE)
- @int(outputs(THE_VARIABLE)
- THE_VARIABLE

None of those works, Does anyone knows how to deal with this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to enter the value of your variable, instead of using the Value text input box inlined with the flow, select the "Expression" option (see red arrow in the image below); in that mode you will be able to use the flow expression language to convert between the string value to an integer value.

[image: Flow image]

Comment: I don't have that link: 'Add dynamic content'

Comment: When you click on the text input box for the value, does it show up?

Comment: Got it! Should I need to create two boxes of 'Initialiaze variable'?

Comment: Depends on what you like; personally I prefer to save all my parameters "as they come" from Power Apps in string variables, and then manipulate them later. But initializing them directly should work fine too.